# MediaMetadataRetriever : app crashes when trying to retrieve album art from mp3 using url

Tags: java, android, mediametadataretriever

What I want to accomplish here is that when I call this method:

```
public void setAlbumArt(int index) {
    android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mmr.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(fullsongpath.get(index).Path));

    byte [] data = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();
    //albumArt is an Imageview object

    // convert the byte array to a bitmap
    if (data != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        albumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //associated cover art in bitmap
        albumArt.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        albumArt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500, 500));
    } else {
        albumArt.setImageResource(R.mipmap.default_album_art); //any default cover resourse folder
        albumArt.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        albumArt.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(500,500 ));
    }
}
```

my app crashes, throwing an error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

This is the albumArt ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/albumArt"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@mipmap/default_album_art" />
```

the `fullsongpath` is an ArrayList holding this object :

```
public class SongInfo {

    public  String Path;
    public  String song_name;
    public  String album_name;
    public  String artist_name;

    public  SongInfo(String Path,String song_name,String album_name,String artist_name){
      this.Path=Path;
      this.song_name=song_name;
      this.album_name=album_name;
      this.artist_name=artist_name;
    }
}
```

the path is the URL for the mp3 file

I really don't know what's causing this problem, I hope that you could help, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: `MediaMetadataRetriever::setDataSource` throws `IllegalArgumentException` if the `String` is `null` ... my guess .. it is `null`?  You should really look at the docs and the source code before posting questions like this because usually the crash is a symptom of another issue.

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

                metaRetriever.setDataSource(model.getPostImage(), new HashMap<String, String>());
                // get mp3 info
                byte[] art = metaRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
                final Bitmap bm2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
                metaRetriever.release();

                holder.postImg.post(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                    holder.postImg.setImageBitmap(bm2);
                  }
                });
              }
            }).start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't know how you populated your PATH but I am suspecting you used `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

There is no Album art for `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

In that case, you need to use `MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`